# Moving window on the screen

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, window-management

Is there any shortcuts to move/drag the  window(box) on the screen when the window is not maximized without changing its dimension? Say I want to drag the vim/emacs editor window to the left side/middle/right side of my screen so it doesn't cover the cmd window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With library [`frame-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/frame-cmds.el) you have commands to move the selected frame around.  Bind them to repeatable keys (just hold the key pressed).

- **`move-frame-left`**  - suggested binding: `M-<left>`.
- **`move-frame-right`** - suggested binding: `M-<right>`.
- **`move-frame-up`**    - suggested binding: `M-<up>`.
- **`move-frame-down`**  - suggested binding: `<M-down>`.

Option **`move-frame-wrap-within-display-flag`** non-`nil` means wrap frame movements within the display.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using vim/etc on a Windows machine, the windows key + a directional arrow should help. I’m not sure if the machine is running Linux or macOS as its primary OS.

Comment: This works, but it changes the shape of the editor window, I was wondering if there's a way to move editor window little by little, without changing the overall shape. But thanks!